# Do PHP PDO prepared statements need to be escaped?

Tags: php, pdo

On the [PDO::Prepare page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) it states,

> "and helps to prevent SQL injection attacks by eliminating the need to manually quote the parameters"

Knowing this, is there a PHP function like mysql_real_escape_string() that takes care of escaping stings for PDO? Or does PDO take care of all escaping for me?

**EDIT**

I realize now that I asked the wrong question. My question really was, "What all does PDO take care of for me?" Which I realize now with these answers that it really only removes the need to escape the quotes. But I would still need to do any other PHP sanitize calls on the values that I pass to the execute function. Such as htmlentities(), strip_tags()...etc...

Comment: There are no universal "sanitization" function in the world. It is like real life: washing hands, using condoms and keeping money in the safe chest are all for safety. But it doesn't mean that your apple, washed and wrapped in condom and put into safe chest, considered to be safe.  Each sanitization function is for it's own purpose. Do not ask HTML safety from the database function. It woul be weird.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel +1 Nice example lol.....

Answer (score 28, accepted):

PDO does not escape the variables. The variables and the SQL command are transferred independently over the MySQL connection. And the **SQL tokenizer (parser) never looks at the values**. Values are just copied verbatim into the database storage without the possibility of ever causing any harm. That's why there is no need to marshall the data with prepared statements.

Note that this is mostly a speed advantage. With mysql_real_escape_string() you first marshall your variables in PHP, then send an inefficient SQL command to the server, which has to costly segregate the actual SQL command from the values again. That's why it's often said that the security advantage is only implicit, not the primary reason for using PDO.

If you concat the SQL command and don't actually use prepared statments (not good!), then yes, there still is an escape function for PDO: [$pdo->quote($string)](http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.quote.php)

Comment: Actually this is incorrect.  Both pdo and adodb use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when connected to mysql.  I've looked though the code.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel pdo is written in c++ and adodb is written in php. They both use mysql_real_escape_string() (which is apart of the offical mysql client library).  You have to escape input at some point,  there is no other way.

Comment: @The Rook: Gauging from http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_statement.c?revision=299574&view=markup it might depend on the backend driver. The new mysqlnd surely uses real prepared statments, while the older might fall back on PDO_ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES and escaping/concatenating. After all, it's one of the advertised features of PDO to emulate it **if** not available.

Answer (score 14):

Very few people here understand what escaping is and when to use it.
Escaping itself does not make any data "safe". It just escapes delimiters, to distinguish a delimiter from a part of data. `field = 'it's me'` will cause an error, while `field = 'it\'s me'` will not. That's the only purpose of escaping. So, it works only when you use quotes. If you don't - escaping becomes useless.

Do you use quotes with placeholders? No. Thus, no escaping would be sensible.

When you are binding your variables, it works a very different way: it does not send the whole query to the server, but sends your prepared query separated from the bound data. So it cannot interfere. And thus makes no injection possible.

Comment: Thank you, once again, @YourCommonSense. 

Answer (score 8):

Yes and no:

- Literals which you embed into the statement string need to be escaped as normal.
- Values which you bind to the prepared statement are handled by the library.

Comment: so if I use the bindParm method i do not need to escape anything to prevent an injection, right?

Comment: @Patareco Values passed to `PDOStatement::bindValue()` or `PDOStatement::bindParam()` (there's an important difference!) should be handled correctly by PDO. You should not escape them, or they'll be stored escaped in the database. I make no guarantees, though; there may be bugs in PDO/PHP/MySQL that allow injection. You also have to handle output correctly to prevent script injection.

Comment: My question was only concerning inserting data in the DB and preventing an SQL injection. You raised an important question that I had not considered. Someone can put some nasty JS that could cause me trouble, luckily PHP has a function to escape HTML Chars. Thank you for the warning!

Answer (score 6):

If you prepare a statement and use [bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) or [bindValue](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) to supply variables, you do not need to escape the variables. Note that these functions assume that the variable contains a string, so use the third parameter to bindValue if you want to use booleans or floats.

Comment: Im using prepare, and execute.....I do not use the bindParam, or bindValue functions.

Comment: @Metropolis: That's fine. If you pass the question mark ? or :named parameters as arguments to ->execute(), it has the same effect as bindParam. Just take care that these should reference text columns then.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to worry about it. PDO does not require you to escape your data before passing it along to the database.

**Edit:** Just to be clear, I mean to say that as long as you are passing variables into your parameters (for example, the value of a form field), you don't have to worry about it. However, if you're passing variables that you've defined as strings, for example, then obviously you need to escape anything that needs escaping in that string in order to avoid breaking syntax. However, this wouldn't even make much sense since one of the main advantages of PDO is that you're passing information from the user to the database without having to sanitize it yourself, and there aren't many times (if any?) that you would be passing strings that you yourself had defined.

Also, make sure you still sanitize your data for *type*. For example, make sure it's an integer if you expect it to be, make sure it's less than or greater than x if you expect it to be, etc.

Comment: Ok cool....so all special characters should be taken care of? Like HTML tags, quotes...etc..

Comment: Assuming that you're binding your parameters to the prepared statement, yes. (Obviously if you're writing the text yourself in PHP code, for example into a variable, then it needs to be escaped so as not to disrupt the syntax.)

Comment: @Metropolis html tags has nothing to do with SQL at all, and quotes doesn't matter for the binding, as there are no delimiting surrounding quotes - so, nothing to escape.

Comment: @Metropolis escaping to prevent SQL injection has nothing to do with html tags etc. You still need to escape stored input when you output it to a webpage if it contains html you don't want parsing etc.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel my question about the HTML was asked because I was wondering if htmlentites needed to be used on the values that I am passing in to replace the (?)'s in the statements.

Comment: @MrXexxed I know that escaping to prevent SQL injection has nothing to do with html tags. My question was, what exactly does PDO take care of for me? Maybe I need to reword this.

Comment: @Metropolis the answer remains the same. it is **html** entities function, not **SQL** entities function. there are a whole lot of escaping functions in PHP - escapeshallcmd(), preg_quote(), etc. **You don't have to use them all** but only ones which applicable for the every particular case.