# PHP PDO Sanitize variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Im working with PDO for the first time and im wondering if the below looks safe, I've tried to read up on alternatives to mysql_real_escape and it seems like the 'prepare' method is sufficient enough security wise, can anyone clarify this for me? Still appears vulnerable...

```
$UID = $_GET['id'];

$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != '' AND ID = :uid");
$sth->execute(array(':uid' => $UID));
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143614/do-php-pdo-prepared-statments-need-to-be-escaped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prepare method is not only sufficient, it's preferred over `mysql_real_escape()`.

Your code works, as `$UID` will be transmitted with a different protocol than the rest of the SQL statement.  Since the database treats it differently, there's no need to escape.