# Should I still escape my data when inserting to custom table?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, pdo, sanitization

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143614/do-php-pdo-prepared-statments-need-to-be-escaped), but it didn't really give me the answer I was looking for. [This tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/data-sanitization-and-validation-with-wordpress/) explains the most important sanitation functions WordPress uses.

I'm using PDO to store form data into custom tables. A lot of this data contains names like `l'this` and `Cotélac & Blancé`.

If I put aside e-mail and url fields, is it enough to use `esc_attr` and `esc_html` to avid SQL injection and cross site scripting?

Should I use this before data is saved to DB? Or just before I out put it to screen?

```
//From Wordpress
esc_html -> Escaping for HTML blocks
esc_attr -> Encodes the <, >, &, " and '
```

This is a typical query I use:

```
$sql = " SELECT name
         FROM name
         WHERE user_name = :user_name
         AND fk_ID = :some_id ";

$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':user_name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':some_id', $some_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
return $result;

// alternative (from another query)
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':id'=> $id));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

return $result;
```

Comment: depends on *how* you're using PDO

Comment: @YourCommonSense I've updated question with query example

Comment: You might wanna read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tagged [wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress), I might add that there is the [$wpdb class](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb_Class) that handles all these.

Yes, and you should use [$wpdb->prepare](http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb_Class#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) to help you with that.

From the example of the Codex:

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
        INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta
        ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value )
        VALUES ( %d, %s, %s )
    ", 
        10, 
    $metakey, 
    $metavalue 
) );
```

Comment: Yes I know. Unfortunately I thought of this 2 years after I started (and I got to know WP a bit more). So now there are a few thousand lines of SQL queries. On the other hand, not using `$wpdb` allows me to more easily port the code over a different system if the need / time comes. Even if I was using `$wpdb`, I should still escape some of the data?

Comment: The `prepare` method will do the necessary for you if you're using `$wpdb`. If in doubt you could hard code some values and try to add it in your wordpress database, just to see that the $wpdb class works how you expect it.

Comment: Ok. But let's assume I'm not planning on using `$wpdb` just yet, how would you solve my problem above?

Comment: Stan gave you a link where this topic is discussed with much details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection