# Escaping $_POST to variables

Tags: php, post, mysqli, escaping

Someone told me that I need to escape $_POST but once I did this my variables are just empty. What am I missing?

```
<?php
$order = $_POST['order'];
$heading = $_POST['heading'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
?>

<?php
echo $order . $heading . $content;

$order = mysqli_real_escape_string($order);
$heading = mysqli_real_escape_string($heading);
$content = mysqli_real_escape_string($content);
?>
<?php
echo $order . $heading . $content;

$sql="INSERT INTO faq (`order`, `heading`, `content`)
VALUES ('$order','$heading','$content')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";
```

Comment: Have you verified that $_POST contains the values you expect?

Comment: Do you need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: Why not prepare it instead?

Comment: you shouldn't be using mysql_ functions anyhow. Look into prepared statements for mysqli.

Comment: For starters, you can't mix and match `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions. They're not interchangeable. You can escape the variables like you are doing (by using `mysqli_real_escape_string`) but the better practice would be to look into _prepared statements_.

Comment: yes, because originally I was using $_POST directly in the query, which I now know is bad

Comment: The mysql_ functions are deprecated, use mysqli or pdo instead. Prepared statements are better for escaping. Yes you have to escape post data for sql if you want to save it to a relational database.

Comment: I changed it to mysqli, still just insert an empty row

Comment: @inf3rno That's not entirely accurate. Only if the values are being dropped straight into the statement, as they are done here, should they need to be escaped. When the values are properly bound ("binded") in the SQL statement, you do not need to escape them because the `query` is sent to the database separately from the `parameters`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143614/do-php-pdo-prepared-statments-need-to-be-escaped#answer-3143650) link for references.

Comment: What happens if you echo your $sql variable before you run the query? What does the actual query look like?

Comment: INSERT INTO faq (`order`, `heading`, `content`) VALUES ('', '', '')

Comment: I just edited the code, the variables echo nothing after the escape string

Comment: According to this post http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php the string will be empty if no connection is open. could that be the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I apologize - I must have been asleep this morning. This is something we should have caught earlier.

There were actually two problems in your original code:

1. Since you're using the `mysqli_*` functions, you need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` instead of the `mysql_real_escape_string()` that was originally in your question. You've already corrected this in the question, but it probably led to us overlooking the second problem.
2. [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) takes different arguments than [`mysql_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php), and the first argument needs to be a connection identifier. If you change your code to this, it should work:

   ```
    $order = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $order);
    $heading = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $heading);
    $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $content);
   ```

---

As many of the comments pointed out, you may also want to look into using [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496) instead.

While the code that you have is now secure from SQL injection, the advantage of prepared statements is that escaping is built in automatically and you don't have to remember to escape your variables every time you do a query.

Comment: I ended up figuring out the prepared statements, I think. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Before you blame the real_escape_string as the problem. Check if there are any values at all.

```
foreach($_POST = $Name => $Value) {
     echo $Name.' '.$Value.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not have `mysqli` enabled in your PHP configuration.  Check your `phpinfo()` to find out.  Info [here](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/764/How+can+I+create+a+phpinfo.php+page?#gs).

Enable it if necessary.  However, the advice to change to `PDO` is good in any case.

Also, assuming you are not on a production server, MAKE SURE YOU HAVE ERRORS SET TO DISPLAY.  Essential for trouble-shooting.

If `mysqli` is not enabled it will result in a fatal error.  Probably one that shows no matter your display settings.  But still, get errors configured to show while you figure this out.