# Do I need to escape my variables when using PDO bindParam?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm writing the following code and want to know if it's still necessary to escape my variables when using `bindParam()`.

```
$usernameCheckQuery = $db->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$usernameCheckQuery->bindParam(":username", $data['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$usernameCheckQuery->execute();
```

I've read on some places that it's not necessary and others that say it is. Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143614/do-php-pdo-prepared-statments-need-to-be-escaped

Answer (score 2):

pdo is doing the escaping, so you do not need to. - There may be other types of verification that you should do, but that depends on your code. For a longer answer, see 
[Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection?rq=1)