# Strip html_tags and extra backslashes from TinyMCE <textarea>

Tags: php, sql-update, tinymce

I am updating blog posts in my own CMS built in PHP and ran locally on XAMPP. I've downloaded the source files for TinyMCE, a WYSIWYG plugin, for adding and editing posts. The editor works fine. It retrieves and submits data as it is supposed to except for one issue; the content submitted in the textarea tag, which includes the TinyMCE object by class name, contains extra backslashes and html tags in the actual blog post display. For example, the line of text

"That's Where CSS(Cascading Style Sheets) comes in. This is the language that formats your page content and styles all of your text, background, images, borders, etc."

when put into the textarea, returns and displays

"That\s Where CSS(Cascading Style Sheets) comes in. This is the language that formats your page content and styles all of your text, background, images, borders, etc. \r\n "

Now here is where I'm confused...

I clean my data before binding it as a parameter in a mysqli prepared statement. I do this by running whatever data I wish to clean through my clean() function defined in functions.php. Shouldn't this take care of the issue (as it always has thus far, before TinyMCE). The cleaning and submitting process of post content is as follows:

**functions.php**

```
    function clean($param){

     global $connection;

     $cleaned = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, trim(strip_tags($param)));

    return cleaned; 

    }
```

**editPost.php**, from which I've omitted some of the original form markup. Only the php handling the form data on submission, the start of the form, the block of code containing the post content, the submit button, and end of form are included. Otherwise you guys would be staring at a lot of fluff unrelated to the question.

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['update_post'])) **{**

    $post_author = clean($_POST['post_author']);
    $post_title = clean($_POST['post_title']);
    $post_category_id = clean($_POST['post_category_id']);
    $post_category = clean($_POST['post_category']);
    $post_status = clean($_POST['post_status']);
    $post_image = $_FILES['post_image']['name'];
    $post_image_temp = $_FILES['post_image']['tmp_name'];
    $post_tags = clean($_POST['post_tags']);
    $post_content= clean($_POST['post_content']);
    $post_comment_count = clean($_POST['post_comment_count']);
    $post_date = clean($_POST['post_date']);

    $query = "UPDATE posts SET post_title = ?, post_category_id = ?, post_date = ?, post_author = ? , post_status = ?, post_tags = ?, post_content = ?, post_image = ? WHERE post_id = ?";  

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $now = date('Y-m-d');

 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($connection);
 mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query);
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sissssssi', $post_title, $post_category_id, $now, $post_author, $post_status, $post_tags, $post_content, $post_image, $post_id);


 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
 echo "<p class='bg-success'>Post Updated. <a href='../post.php?p_id={$get_post_id}'>View Post, </a> or <a href='posts.php'>Edit More Posts</a></p>";

    }

    ?>

     <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label for="post_content">Post Content </label>

     <textarea type="text" class="form-control tinymce" name="post_content" 
      cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $post_content; ?>
     </textarea>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
     <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="update_post" value="Update Post">
 </div>
```

***admin_footer.php,*** rendered with ***editPost.php***

```
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> 
    </script>
    <script src ="js/plugins/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="js/plugins/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea.tinymce",
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink link image lists print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media",
            "save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor"
            ],

        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic underline | 
         alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist 
         outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | 
         forecolor backcolor emoticons"



    });
    </script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I've never gotten these extra characters before using TinyMCE. The clean function has worked for me every other time. The only thing to change is this WYSIWYG editor, so I'm confident the problem originates from them. Is there a workaround I could add to clean()? *I've already tried to add*  **html_entity_decode($cleaned)** and
**htmlspecialchars_decode($cleaned)**, but with no luck. Nothing changed

```
    function clean($param){
    global $connection;
    $cleaned = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, trim(strip_tags($param)));
    html_entity_decode($cleaned);
    htmlspecialchars_decode($cleaned);
    return $cleaned;

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do PHP PDO prepared statements need to be escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143614/do-php-pdo-prepared-statements-need-to-be-escaped)

Comment: Dupe is for PDO (which is the better tool to use, IMO) but the same applies to mysqli. You're double escaping and that's why you end up with escape characters in your stored data.

Comment: Thanks a lot, miken32! You're right. No escaping is necessary in this context. I took out clean() and it worked like a charm. Sorry, I'm still rather new to php and just updated every query to my db into prepared statements a few days ago. I guess there's no need for clean() anymore, now that the queries are in this format. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help. I second my recommendation for PDO rather than mysqli. Much easier to use: no parameter binding, no counting your "s" and "i", useful methods like `fetchAll`, and a modern object interface.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As the project is still fairly young, I'll probably make the switch. Counting parameters and listing their data types in order has definitely been an annoying task. Again, much appreciated!